# How would you access Eclipse JDT index?

Tags: java, eclipse, indexing

How do I access the index that eclipse uses to do Java search, import, etc?

Comment: can you please elaborate. i dont understand what you are saying and what is seach?

Comment: @Pavan: I assume a JDT (Java) context for this question (and I have edited it accordingly). I have posted an answer in that context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [old thread (for eclipse2!)](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipse-dev/msg02206.html) mentioned:

In the meantime if you feel like indexes are not complete (`open type` doesn't show you a type which it should), you can workaround by:

> - exiting Eclipse,
> - find the index files in the metadata, and discard them all.
> - Restart Eclipse,
> - and activate the open-type dialog which will trigger proper reindexing.
>
> Index files are located in:
>   **`<workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core/`**, you want to get rid of all '`*.index`' files in the doubt + '`savedIndexNames.txt`'.

I just checked with my current Eclipse Helios 3.6.1, and those files are still around.

---

More generally (and programmatically), the [SearchParticipant API](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/search/package-summary.html) is involved with those files, ans mentioned in [bug 308402](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=308402)

> `SearchParticipant` has the method `#selectIndexes` and part of its documentation
>   says "An index location represents a path in the file system to a file that
>   holds index information." and to that effect we store our `.index` files in our
>   own location and return those when the `#selectIndexes` method is called using
>   the `BasicSearchEngine`.

You can see an [example here](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.jdt/msg20905.html).

Comment: Good answer, but I wanted to access it programatically.

Comment: I was asking about the same thing more or less here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19337409/eclipse-cleanup-what-are-the-index-files-can-i-safely-delete-them. Are those index files just that ? Or do they "index" more things ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D no, they are internal files that will be re-generated if need be.