# Information about JDT index format

Tags: java, eclipse, search, indexing, eclipse-jdt

I'm looking for information about the JDT index. For example what the format is, how the data is structured (Documents? Fields?). Information on that topic seems to be scarce. The ansers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898185/how-would-you-access-eclipse-jdt-index) didn't help yet. [Here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/tree/63389/#page_top) I found a hint to look for the JavaSearchPattern hierarchy but it's rather hard to understand. I wonder if there is some better source of information.

Can someone please point me into the right direction?

Comment: Why is that question relevant for you? An index is normally only good to use for the one that creates it, not for others ...

Comment: I'm doing research for my Master thesis and would like to understand how the JDT sort of maps the AST to an index efficiently

Comment: Please post this question on JDT forums - eclipse.org/forums. Someone from JDT/Core team should respond.

Comment: Thanks. Did it. To follow up: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/849875/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See thread http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/849875/ for a quick overview