# Eclipse error ... cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a dynamic web project that I am working on to migrate a jsp/servlet app from JRun to Tomcat.

I am getting the error:  `com.ibm.ivj.eab.dab.DatastoreJDBC` cannot be resolved to a type.

I have the `*.class` files sitting inside a `com/ibm/ivj/eab/dab` folder (exactly how I found them).  I have tried creating a jar file and adding that to the build path via "Add External Jar", I have also tried adding an "External Class Folder" and pointing to the folder that contains the "com" directory in question.

Still, the error persists.  What is strange is if I start typing the package name eclipse actually auto-completes the class for me!  (pictured below).  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Maybe the classes were compiled for a much older java version and that is causing trouble?  Maybe there is something I need to do to ensure the classes end up in the WEB-INF/lib directory?

I[image]

Comment: Is there an import statement in your code for the class?

Comment: @ChrisGerken no I did just add <%@page import="com.ibm.ivj.eab.dab.*"%> to the top (this is a JSP page) and also 
<%@page import="com.ibm.ivj.eab.dab.DatastoreJDBC"%>  what is interesting is Eclipse doesn't mind the first import but marks the second as an error.

Comment: No matter if Eclipse or Intellij, this is one of the most annoying errors of modern IDE's.It is almost always caused by a cache behavior, therefore you will receive answers like "clean the cache", "restart", and so on. The cache is build for performance, and the IDE is not able to understand that a change occurred and therefore you need to clean the cache manually.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

1. Right click your project name.
2. Click `Properties`.
3. Click `Java Build Path`.
4. Click on `Add Class Folder`.
5. Then choose your class.

Alternatively, `Add Jars` should work although you claim that you attempted that.

Also, "have you tried turning it off and back on again"? (Restart Eclipse).

Comment: When I "Add Class Folder" should I pick the folder that contains the "com" directory (the great-great grandaddy) or should I pick the folder that contains the *.class files?

Comment: Found a different, more extensive set of packages including this one, rolled that into a jar, and so far so good.  Thanks!

Comment: It definitely seems like eclipse can be a bit buggy when it comes to the validation of JSPs.  "Turning it off and back on again" helps it regain its footing, but I also found that performing a Project -> Clean... can help as well to set things straight.

Comment: Which class needs to be selected here?

Comment: When I added class folders, Eclipse hid them from project view. When I removed (at the same place in build path wizard where I've added them before) them, everything was working like a charm.

Comment: try this if any of comments is not working - http://www.kyleclegg.com/blog/eclipse-android-error-type-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: Restarting Eclipse is what did it for me!

Answer (score 72):

Also If you are using mavenised  project  then  try  to update your project by clicking  Alt+F5. 
Or right click on the application and go to maven /update project.

It builds all your components and resolves if any import error is there.

Comment: Can someone explain why it is necessarily to do this? Why eclipse can't figure it out by itself?

Comment: I had this issue and tried updating maven project countless times but it did not solve it until I deleted JDT indexes like this: [answer on How would you access Eclipse JDT index?] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3898528/6359607)

Comment: This worked for me. But it makes no sense why eclipse does not do this on its own.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Is there a way of adding a mvn command line into eclipse execution?

Comment: I am running a multi maven project eclipse 4.15.0 and it looks good for all individual projects. However, it fails for the multi maven project.

Answer (score 21):

To solve the error "...cannot be resolved to a type.." do the followings:

1. Right click on the class and select "Build Path-->Exclude"
2. Again right click on the class and select "Build Path-->Include"

It works for me.

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways to solve the issue "cannot be resolved to a type
":

1. For non maven project, add jars manually in a folder and add it in java build path. This would solve the compilation errors.
2. For maven project, right click on the project and go to maven -> update project. Select all the projects where you are getting compilation errors and also check "Force update of snapshots/releases". This will update the project and fix the compilation errors.

Comment: maven -> update project does solve my issue but as soon as after code edit when i do project->clean->build all, all 10k+ "cannot be resolved to a type " errors re-appear.

Answer (score 7):

Project -> Clean

can at least sometimes be sufficient to resolve the matter.

Answer (score 6):

For maven users:

- Right click on the project
- Maven
- Update Project

Comment: For me, in addition, after running maven-update-project on all projects, I sometimes have to then do a maven-update-project on our core library. Oddly, both steps are necessary in that order.

Answer (score 4):

- Right click **Project** > **Properties**
- **Java Build Path** > **Add Class Folder**
- Select the **bin** folder
- Click **ok**
- Switch **Order and Export** tab
- Select the newly added bin path move **UP**
- Click **Apply** button

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Easy Solution:
Go to

> Project property -> java builder path -> maven -> find c3p0-0.9.5.2.jar

and see the location where the file is stored in the local repository and go to this location and delete the repository manually.

[image: G]

Answer (score 1):

```
Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path
Select Java Build path on the left menu, and select "Source"
 click on Excluded and then Include(All) and then click OK
    Cause : The issue might because u might have deleted the CLASS files 
 or dependencies on the project
```

For maven users:

Right click on the project

Maven

Update Project

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by dropping the jar into WEB_INF/lib.

Answer (score 0):

copying the jar files will resolve. If by any chance you are copying the code from any tutorials, make sure the class names are spelled in correct case...for example i copied a code from one of the tutorials which had solr in S cap. Eclipse was continiously throwing the error and i also did a bit of googling ...everything was ok and it took 30 mins for me to realise the cap small issue. Am sure this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

For many new users don't forget to add an asterisk (*) after your import statements if you wanna use all the classes in a package....for example

```
import java.io.*;

public class Learning 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        BufferedInputStream sd = new BufferedInputStream(System.in);
            // no error
    }
}
```

================================================================

```
import java.io;

public class Learning 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        BufferedInputStream sd = new BufferedInputStream(System.in);
            // BufferedInputStream cannot be resolved to a type error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution** : 
1.Project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path

2.Select Java Build path on the left menu, and select "Source"

3.Under Project select Include(All) and click OK

**Cause** : 
The issue might because u might have deleted the CLASS files or dependencies on the project

Answer (score 0):

First you need to update the pom.xml by adding below

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

1] Right click your project name.

2] Click Properties.

3] Click Java Build Path.

4] Check on 'Maven Dependencies' in Order and Export tabl.

In my case, previously it was not enabled. So when I enabled it my @GetMapping annotation works fine..

Answer (score 0):

Also, there is the solution for IvyDE users. Right click on project -> Ivy -> resolve
It's necessary to set ivy.mirror property in build.properties

Answer (score 0):

I just closed all the files and reopened them, and voila!!! Hope this helps someone in the future ;)

Answer (score 0):

Download servlet-api.jar file and paste it in WEB-INF folder it will work

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)
For example you can add a link where to download from and explain how can it be that this jar was missing in the first place.