# Python / Sentiment Analysis: Unable to execute NLP codes in Eclipse

Tags: java, python, eclipse, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to run the following code on Python, Eclipse for NLP but unable to execute the same. I am trying to run Sentiment Analysis by creating Twitter API to fetch data from Twitter. I am running the following code:

[Code on Eclipse for running Sentiment Analysis using Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrWqi.jpg)

I have picked up the codes from http://rahular.com/twitter-sentiment-analysis/

Please help me with the resolution for the same.

Comment: It seems like it cannot find the jar files. Did you [Extract files and copy the following files into your project’s lib folder **and add it to Java Build Path**](http://rahular.com/twitter-sentiment-analysis/)?

Comment: yes u can see in picture which i have attached

Comment: You could try the [answers that were given here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794821/eclipse-error-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type)...

Comment: There is an error in- import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP;

Comment: The question is different, the solution may be the same: restart Eclipse, update project, etc..