# Using JAVA API for Hbase

Tags: hbase

I used the following code to create a table in Hbase :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HColumnDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin;

public class MyfirstHBaseTable
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    HBaseConfiguration hconfig = new HBaseConfiguration(new Configuration());
    HTableDescriptor htable = new HTableDescriptor("User"); 
    htable.addFamily( new HColumnDescriptor("Id"));
    htable.addFamily( new HColumnDescriptor("Name"));
    System.out.println( "Connecting..." );
    HBaseAdmin hbase_admin = new HBaseAdmin( hconfig );
    System.out.println( "Creating Table..." );
    hbase_admin.createTable( htable );
    System.out.println("Done!");
  }
}
```

But got the following error:

[image]

Can anyone suggest what else needs to be done ?

Comment: Looks like the HBase dependencies are missing from your build.

Comment: Actually I am begineer in that can u please elaborate your suggestion and how to fix it .I have added all the libraries in eclipse project from Hbase

Comment: How are you doing your builds and managing dependencies? You should edit the question to include that information.

Comment: Some basic information on this type of problem is in this old question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794821/eclipse-error-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type

Comment: I am done .I just added all the libraries and it is working .Thank you !!!

Comment: Great, best of luck !

Comment: I am getting cross sign when using                                              HbaseAdmin admin = new HbaseAdmin(conf); cross on HbaseAdmin Whyy???

Comment: Usage of the library is a separate question from resolving the dependencies - you should ask a new question.