# Jasper Reports compile ERROR

Tags: java, maven, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I'm getting a problem when I try to compile my Java code, using Jasper Reports

I have followed this tutorial: https://www.mkyong.com/java/reporting-in-java-using-dynamicreports-and-jasperreports/

That's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/jasper", "root", "root");

    JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();// a new report

    report.columns(Columns.column("Customer Id", "id", DataTypes.integerType()),
            Columns.column("First Name", "first_name", DataTypes.stringType()),
            Columns.column("Last Name", "last_name", DataTypes.stringType()),
            Columns.column("Date", "date", DataTypes.dateType()))
            .title(// title of the report
                    Components.text("SimpleReportExample").setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER))
            .pageFooter(Components.pageXofY())// show page number on the
                                                // page footer
            .setDataSource("SELECT id, first_name, last_name, date FROM customers", connection);

}
```

That's my pom.xml'dependences:

```
<dependencies>
        <!-- DynamicReports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.dynamicreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>dynamicreports-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My strack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    JasperReportBuilder cannot be resolved to a type
    DynamicReports cannot be resolved
    Columns cannot be resolved
    DataTypes cannot be resolved
    Columns cannot be resolved
    DataTypes cannot be resolved
    Columns cannot be resolved
    DataTypes cannot be resolved
    Columns cannot be resolved
    DataTypes cannot be resolved
    Components cannot be resolved
    HorizontalAlignment cannot be resolved to a variable
    Components cannot be resolved

    at test.Test.main(Test.java:20)
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using Eclipse Neon

Comment: Looks like a problem with your Eclipse. There are a lot of posts at SO with similar problem at Eclipse. You can look at [Eclipse error … cannot be resolved to a type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15794821/876298)

Comment: BTW, Do you have imports at class?

Comment: yes, Alex, I tried to use in pom.xml the following dependency:

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.5</version>
</dependency>

And I cannot import the class

Comment: I will try to see if this is an eclipse problem. thanks

Comment: I did import with. <dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>5.6.1</version>
</dependency>