# Documentation for Swagger annotations that work with io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI

Tags: java, annotations, swagger, openapi

I'm looking for documentation that describes the Swagger annotations that the io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI class will detect when generating a swagger file from Java resources. I have tried using annotations from [this Wiki page](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-2.X---Annotations)  and they throw errors in my project.

[image]

The error is "cannot be resolved to a type". Eclipse cannot find a class for this annotation

Comment: The page you linked to is in fact the documentation for `io.swagger.v3.*` annotations. Are you sure your project uses Swagger Core 2.x and not the older Swagger Core 1.x?

Comment: I needed to add this class to my project's build path.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse error ... cannot be resolved to a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15794821/eclipse-error-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-type)